# retrieve max date record out of group of records

Tags: sql, oracle, max

I have the following oracle table with the below 3 columns. As you can see, I have the same contract_number related to different card number and different date_open. I need to retrieve the max date for each contract_number

```
CONTRACT_NUMBER    CARD_NUMBER          DATE_OPEN

009-P-0000202      1236547896542145    11/23/2012
009-P-0000202      5555666644441111    6/20/2014
009-P-0000202      6655225544665878    6/25/2014
009-P-008880       9666998775458789    5/16/2011
009-P-008880       4561637899876435    1/22/2013
009-P-0010873      6456879413185467    5/14/2013
009-P-0200749      5000223365521456    2/28/2013
009-P-098538       1000222266669870    12/19/2011
009-P-098538       1000222266665555    3/22/2012
009-P-098538       1000222266667777    7/27/2012
009-P-098538       1000222266669995    2/27/2013
009-P-098538       1000222266663333    3/22/2013
009-P-098538       1000222266661222    4/18/2013
009-P-098538       1000222266667567    7/26/2013
009-P-098538       1000222266669876    1/10/2014
009-P-098538       1000222266664456    6/13/2014
009-P-098538       1000222266663345    8/19/2014
009-P-098538       1000222266662321    12/5/2014
```

the desired result should look like the below:

```
CONTRACT_NUMBER    CARD_NUMBER          DATE_OPEN

009-P-0000202      6655225544665878    6/25/2014
009-P-008880       4561637899876435    1/22/2013
009-P-0010873      6456879413185467    5/14/2013
009-P-0200749      5000223365521456    2/28/2013
009-P-098538       1000222266662321    12/5/2014
```

Appreciate your input

Comment: possible duplicate of [Oracle group part of row and get row with latest timestamp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27563797/oracle-group-part-of-row-and-get-row-with-latest-timestamp) (have a look at the second answer)

Comment: @Peter Lang: He does not specify which values of Card Number he needs displayed... nor can we imply from the "expected results". The problem definition states "I need to retrieve the max date for each contract number" only).

Comment: If you need the  row for which the `DATE_OPEN` is maximum in each group of `CONTRACT_NUMBER`, then see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your problem, looks like you are after a simple group by.

```
SELECT t.Contract_Number,
       MAX(t.card_number) as MaxCardNumber,
       MAX(t.Date_Open) as maxDate
FROM yourTableName t
GROUP BY t.Contract_Number
```

Note that you will get the max card number as well. You must apply an aggregation function to card number as well, if you want to get a list grouped by contract number only.

Comment: there is typo error in `MAX(t.card_number) as MaxCardNumber, MAX(t.Date_Open) as maxDate`

Comment: what is it ? the table fields are conctract_number, card_number and date_open

Comment: comma missing in your answer after `MaxCardNumber`

Comment: Just for language purism, it was not a type, but a syntax error :-)

Comment: If OP wants the row for the maximum date in each group of cardnumber, then this answer would give incorrect result. Since, `max(t.cardnumber)` would fetch the max cardnumber as well.

Comment: Problem is the problem definition is not clear. I am unable to determine what the requirement is regarding the "card number" column. I agree with your remark, and that's why I added my own remark below the answer, stating that this solution will give him the max card number as well, for each contract number.

Comment: @Veverke, I'd say that is a typo which causes a syntax error, but it's still a typo. A typo is a typographical error made while typing on a computer. (In the same way as writing "type" when you try to type "typo".)

Answer (score 0):

You could use **ROW_NUMBER** analytic function.

```
WITH DATA AS(
SELECT t.*,
              ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CONTRACT_NUMBER     
                                     ORDER BY DATE_OPEN DESC) AS rn
         FROM my_table t
)
SELECT CONTRACT_NUMBER, CARD_NUMBER, DATE_OPEN
FROM DATA 
WHERE rn = 1
/
```

Replace `mytable` with your actual table name.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
WHERE  date_open IN (SELECT MAX(date_open)
                     FROM   table_name
                     GROUP BY
                            CONTRACT_NUMBER
                     ORDER BY
                            date_open DESC)
ORDER BY
       date_open DESC
```

Comment: Your subquery is wrong. It will throw `ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression`.

Comment: Remove the invalid ORDER BY from the sub-select, and it will execute. (But return wrong result...)

Answer (score 0):

Use a sub-query to find the MAX date for each CONTRACT_NUMBER:

```
select * from table t1
where DATE_OPEN = (select max(DATE_OPEN) from table t2
                   where t1.CONTRACT_NUMBER = t2.CONTRACT_NUMBER)
```

If a max date has several CONTRACT_NUMBER rows, all of them will be returned.